# If cell contains partial string, then change cell value

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a list of hundreds of companies in a column. There are repeat companies that were inputted differently. (i.e. "Nike" vs "Nike Inc")

I am trying to program a macro in excel to loop through the column to search for "Nike" and if found it will replace what is in that cell to a consistent company name (i.e. "Nike, Inc.") The goal would be to have the macro search for many companies.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for *Nike* and *Ford*

```
Sub Company()
    ary = Array("Nike", "Ford")
    Dim v As String, i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        v = ary(i)
        For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If InStr(1, Cells(j, "A"), v) > 0 Then
                Cells(j, "A") = v
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Expand **ary()** as required.

Comment: The only suggestion I would make to this would be to not statically assign values in the comparison array.  I would have a config sheet that contains the values I want each to be, and then load that into the comparison array.

Comment: That works well. However, what if I need a company name to be changed to "Nike, Inc."? In other words, I search for "Nike" and if found it changes cell to "Nike, Inc."

Comment: @vbnoob can you give an example of how you would do that?

Comment: Before replacing "Nike" with "Nike, Inc." you first need to check that the cell doesn't already contain "Nike, Inc."

Answer (score 0):

```
dim configSht as WorkSheet, compArray() as String, x as Integer
set configSht = thisWorkbook.Sheets("Config")'This identifies your config sheet
redim compArray(0)
for x = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   if Cells(x,"A")<>"" then
       compArray(UBound(compArray) = Cells(Rows.Count, "A")

   End IF
   reDim Preserve compArray(UBound(compArray)+1)
Next
```

That is a very basic idea.  then you'd use `compArray` in place of `ary` in @Gary's Student solution.  The Comparison array would contain the information you want the cell to read after running the code.  So if you are wanting "Nike Inc." for all instances of "Nike" then "Nike Inc." would be in your config.